# Pig UDF receives or uses wrong parameter

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera, oozie, hue

I am running a pig script trough Oozie.
The script uses a UDF.

The UDF gets its parameters like this:

```
public Float exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

    if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
        return new Float(0);

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(UDFContext.getUDFContext().getJobConf());

    String firstModel = input.get(1).toString();

    InputStream firstModel = fs.open(new Path(firstModel));
    ...
```

In the Oozie debug, the ingoing parameter seems to be ok:

```
  -param
  firstModel_firstscript=./en-sent.bin
```

in the script itself it looks like this:

```
%DEFAULT firstModel_firstscript 'somedefaultstuffthatisntused/firstmodel.bin';
...
myUDF(document, '$firstModel_firstscript', '$secondmodel_firstscript', '$lastmodel_firstscript') AS score;
```

The same results go for

```
myUDF(document, '${firstModel_firstscript}', '${secondmodel_firstscript}', '${lastmodel_firstscript}') AS score;
```

in STDERR it reads:

```
ERROR 2078: Caught error from UDF: my.domain.udf.myUDF [File does not exist: /user/cloudera/firstmodel_firstscript
```

note that it isn't the directory that I should have passed.

I'm at a loss here....
Hope I explained my situation clear enough.

Regards

Comment: is the file located in HDFS or local file system?

Comment: and you're running pig in mapreduce mode?

Comment: Yes I am, another script with as simple text file also located in ./ on the HDFS does run correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was passing hadoop settings in my script the wrong way.

Using:

```
set xyz firstmodel_firstscript;
```

instead of

```
set xyz $firstmodel_firstscript;
```

even tough the values were already set via %default, this is still the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think parameters are case sensitive. You pass `firstModel_firstscript`, but you use `firstmodel_firstscript` in the pig script.
Hope that helps.

Also, please try to access your variables in pig as follows:

`${firstmodel_firstscript}`

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.3_Pig_Action

Comment: I changed the names in the above code for readability reasons, in the actual script they all have the same name across the board.

Comment: does it work when you do not pass a parameter and pass the file to the udf directly? In other words, is it a problem of the udf or a problem of passing the parameter?

Comment: `[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1200: <file entity-matcher.pig, line 26, column 29>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '.' '

I think the . is the first . in ./binfile.bin

Comment: try '${firstmodel_firstscript}' (with quotes)

Comment: I tried that just now and now I get something less helpful as an error message:

    `[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats  - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: AttemptID:attempt_1406704111487_0008_m_000000_3 Info:Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.`

EDIT:
Somewhere higher up I get the same message as before, namely
    `[File does not exist: /user/cloudera/firstmodel_firstscript`

Comment: So in other words: the '${somevariable}' does not write the variable but just the name of the variable, beeing somevariable in this case, right?

Comment: no, that should be replaced by the value of the variable

Comment: hmm this is quite the conundrum then ... Why doesn't it find the variable in the UDF?

Comment: `md5OfDocument = FOREACH documents
GENERATE
 MD5(document) AS key:chararray,
 document AS text:chararray,
 myudf(document, '$firstModel_firstscript', '$secondmodel_firstscript', '$lastmodel_firstscript') AS score
;`

again I've changed the model names for readability

Comment: I meant the action inside oozie. Is it a pig action or a java action?

Comment: it says `Info:Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException:`

So I assume it's a pig action?